# How to bundle a HTML5 JavaScript game as native Windows application?

Tags: html5

As the web browsers evolve, HTML5 game development with JavaScript, Canvas, webgl is increasingly becoming popular. The advantage of web-based games compared to native apps is that they run on multiple platforms, and you don't have to fiddle with OS-specific libraries or programming environments.

You can already sell your web games via the [chrome web store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore), but I think it's too unpopular yet for being profitable for indie game developers.

I think you may reach a larger crowd by selling your games at the Mac App Store or Steam, but therefore you have to bundle it as standalone application.

For mac, you can easily bundle your HTML5 games as native app by using the Apple's WebView component. [Here is an example on how to do that](http://blog.lostdecadegames.com/how-to-embed-html5-into-a-native-mac-osx-app).

Now I wonder: is there an equivalent way for Windows platform?

Comment: "they run on multiple platforms"... slow as hell.
There is no way of creating complexe good-looking games with Browsers without involving third-party system based software.
Totally hyped

Comment: Yes, you can use node-webkit to bundle your game as OSX, Windows and Linux apps: <https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit> It's very easy to use.

Answer (score 7):

I've been targeting [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) for my html5/js game. Most of my code runs browser-side, so the node.js aspects are mostly because its simple enough to have it run a small server and send down the html/js code to the embedded browser.

A good demo of a fast-paced game is, "A Wizard's Lizard". They talk about their success [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamedev/comments/2ioyzg/a_wizards_lizard_by_the_numbers_our_html5_game_on/), and they apparently use node-webkit.

The people behind "Gamedev Tycoon" released [their steamworks integration api as open source](https://github.com/greenheartgames/greenworks). It lets you interact with steam's innards from node-webkit.

A popular (read: newbie friendly) game development platform "[Construct 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/227240/)" lets you create simplistic games using html5/canvas behind the scenes. They also use node-webkit to package up the game as an executable. My non-programmer friend with an digital-media background picked it up fairly quickly. I hosted a [small demo of his first test game](http://praetorlabs.com/projects/tile/c2_2014-04-16/) as an example.

Another option, if you don't want to go with html/javascript (but still want a browser based game) is to use either the [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) framework or the [Unreal Engine](https://www.unrealengine.com/what-is-unreal-engine-4). The Unreal Engine may not have full support currently, but according to [their roadmap](https://trello.com/c/YD6RV75q) it is becoming a first class feature. It was fairly easy to integrate serverside stuff with them and the engines both have great integration with popular services and can be made to interact with server-side elements quite easily. You can read more about how they are integrating with the web on [mozilla's new blog post on the subject](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2014/11/massive-the-asm-js-benchmark/).

All of these work well with [itch.io](http://itch.io) - which is where I'm hoping to publish.

Comment: A quick and easy route with node-webkit: https://github.com/jyapayne/Web2Executable/releases

Answer (score 3):

If I'm not mistaken, the Winforms API in the .NET Framework has a web browser component that you can add to an application, to display HTML content, and modify via a simple interface. It relies on an already installed web browser (usually IE), so you'd have to verify that the user has everything necessary to view your game, but other than that, I don't see why it wouldn't work.

[This](http://frazzleddad.blogspot.com/2007/07/working-with-webbrowser-control-in.html) looks promising. Hope I helped :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Qt with the QtWebkit widget, which will work on all major platforms.

Answer (score 1):

[Titanium Desktop](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-desktop-application-development/) offers a HTML5 CSS3 Javascript plataform for making native apps for Windows,
the only disadvantage is that the source code of the app stays totally open for anyone to edit or see.